# What are the consequences/side effects of deleting STALE records from Oracle DB with Large Data?

Tags: sql, oracle, delete-row, sql-delete

This may sound like a silly questions. 
However, one of the easiest solutions to keep my data consistent is to delete **STALE** records from my DB Table. My table has millions of row.

Can anyone please tell me consequences/side-effects of deleting data from DB.

This DB will be heavy read and medium writes.

Any predictions or 2 cents here before I learn it the hard way on the production website? Will thereby unwanted side-effects caused by inserts & deletes?

**[UPDATE]**

1. One of the plausible solutions I have in mind is:
   I have always have options of adding another column to determine if the data is stale or not. However, with this solution, I need to keep track of another variable.
2. An event is fired which indicates that a single row in the Table is stale. We plan to delete the row when the event is fired.

Comment: Things that rely on that data will now fail?  Do you have a test environment? Backups? Maybe do a sample selection that you can restore easily

Comment: Yeah. We are currently in our design phase. And this is like a critical design question. So we are hoping to fix it at an early stage. Otherwise, the only option left would be to run some sample testing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "stale" data? And why do you need to delete it to make it "consistent"? If the data is only consistent when you remove "wrong" data then you need to fix your application to not insert that "inconsistent" data in the first place.

Comment: So if the record doesn't exist in the table[Lookup], I will fetch the data from another table and update the Lookup table. This table[Lookup] will provide me further optimizations. Something similar to cache. Unfortunately I cannot use cache in my situation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : At the time of insertion it was consistent. However, due to certain other updates, its not consistent anymore now.

Comment: Then I would call those "other updates" a bug - no change in the database should lead to inconsistent data. That's what constraints are for.

Comment: I understand your POV. Unfortunately, In our case, the other updates are valid. My Table is just quick lookup. Anyways, I think this is digressing away from my actual question.

Comment: I would add another column to determine whether the row is stale or not and then create a view that only shows not stale data.

Comment: May be a silly question but would you be deleting the "stale" data in bulk or one by one. If your plan is in bulk and you now intend to atomically mark the record as stale then instead of updating the record to set it as stale why not just delete them as atomically as required?

Comment: One by one. An event is fired which will indicate that the data in a row is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a hand-written chache? That cache may expose two kinds of inconsistencies:

- There are rows in the cache which shouldn't be there
- There are rows missing in the cache which should be there

The latter does not seem to be a problem you worry about.

Deleting rows from the cache in order to fix the first issue would not be much a problem. However, how do you know *when* to delete them. You would need to keep track of whether the cache is dirty or not. Doing this for the whole table is already not easy. Doing it for individual rows is even more difficult.

My experience with such caches is: *don't do it* unless you absolutely have to. Millions of rows does not justify an extra cache per se, this is still a "small table".

The difficulties are often underestimated and the performance benefits are often overestimated. Often you find yourself fixing bugs by writing additional code, which in the end eats up all your performance benefits.

More than once I've been in a situation where we eventually threw away such a cache, because it had become unmanageable. And amazingly the much simpler code we ended up with was still fast enough.

If you really *have to* use a cache I would opt for a materialzed view, where invalidations are tracked by oracle. But first make sure it is really needed and don't fall for premature optimizations.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question. I didn't expect that my question would raise eye brows on the validity of the my DB which acts as a cache here. An event is fired which will indicate that the row in the LookUp table is stale.